# How to parse a String, using a certain pattern, in PHP? (to add some style-tags)

Tags: php

I have Strings and want to parse them with PHP to insert some appropriate style tags.

Example String (don't ask for sense):

`Lorem Ipsum 1.39 (+10% Taxes) Dolor Sit Amet 500 (+50% More) Lorem Ipsum 1.99 (+20% Stupid Taxes) and one more number 123 (+10/20/30% Taxes) Period.`

In this example I always want to find parts with the pattern `(+<number> <text>)` and wrap it into a `<span>`-Tag for styling. I want to search `<text>` for keywords (in this example: `taxes` and `more`) to find out what style to apply though. The Example String above should become:

`Lorem Ipsum 1.39 <span class="taxes">(+10% Taxes)</span> Dolor Sit Amet 500 <span clas="more">(+50% More)</span> Lorem Ipsum 1.99 <span class="taxes">(+20% Stupid Taxes)</span> and one more number 123 <span class="taxes">(+10/20/30% Taxes)</span> Period.`

What is the best way to do this? I'm not sure if `preg_replace()` can do this (neither if regex is the best way to do this). The keywords for `<text>` (here: `taxes` and `more`) are predefined and can be hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\(\+[\/\d]+% ([^)]+)\)/', function($matches) {
  // Make a valid class identifier
  $class = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($matches[1]));
  // Wrap everything in a <span>
  return "<span class='$class'>{$matches[0]}</span>";
}, $string);
```

Comment: This is almost what I wanted. Taking your code, now I want to search in `$class` for certain keywords and then apply an appropriate span-class, but that's simply done with `strpos()`. Thanks for helping with the regex and the very helpful callback function!